# Suggest [rounding] [number-rounding] to the nearest tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I’ve noticed that there are two different tags for rounding numbers to an approximate value.

- [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding) has 3870 questions and already has the synonym [round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/round)
- [number-rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-rounding) has 126 questions.

Their tag excerpts clearly describe the same thing:

[rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding)

> Rounding a numerical value means replacing it by another value that is approximately equal but has a shorter, simpler, or more explicit representation.

[number-rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-rounding)

> Number rounding refers to the process of rounding numbers to a certain digit place (i.e. 1.45 rounded to the nearest tenth is 1.5).

Therefore, I suggest these two tags should be merged, with [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding) being the master tag.

---

It looks like [the synonym has finally been proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rounding/synonyms) after a long time.

Comment: Everybody and his brother knows something about rounding.  These tags are useless to find an expert.  But they are very decent contextual tags, it doesn't matter what their names are.  Always avoid fixing a non-existing problem.

Comment: @Hans You really think we should keep separate [rounding] and [number-rounding] tags? I feel the same way you do about mass "burnination" events, but this would be a simple matter of creating a synonym and merging the tags together. It could be done by a moderator in a matter of moments, with no disruption. Only argument I could see here would be if [number-rounding] referred to floating-point rounding, but then, um, [floating-point-rounding] would be a better choice for a name. :-)

Comment: I agree, as long as some rough equivalent to the rounding to significant figures part is edited in to the tag description.